# MVC 2 - error messages to be rendered in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using DataAnnotations for form field validation. So for example I have a contact model with the below property:

```
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your first name.")]  
   [StringLength(100)]
   public string   FirstName      { get; set; }
```

But instead of the error appearing at the side of each control, I need them to appear in a list above the form itself.  What is the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)  // to not show property error
 @Html.ValidationSummary(false)  // to include property errors
```

Put that on top or whereever in your form and it'll summarize all your validation errors.

Comment: That works, but the validation errors still appear at the side of each control.  Is there a way of preventing that?  Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah,  remove the validatefor statements after each property